# Object does not appear in my table. I'm trying to learn how to add an Object to the DOM with an IIFE and JSON

Tags: javascript, dom

I don't know how to do debugging please be patient I'm a beginner and my Object does not appear on my body, I really do not know how to go on and where my problem... I think it can be that my addListItem function breaking when it tries to create a button and again when the listener is activated.

also, my details.sprites do not recognize...

my HTML is very simple and has only in the body, main and div and inside the div my ul class pokemon-list.

```
//IIFE
var pokemonRepository = (function () {
  var pokemonList = [];
  var apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150'; function loadList() {
      document.write("loadList");
      return fetch(apiUrl).then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
          document.write("loadList fetch \n");
}).then(function (json) {
          document.write("loadList then \n");

          json.results.forEach(function (item) {    //result /results
              var pokemon = {
                  name: item.name,
                  detailsUrl: item.url
              };
              add(pokemon);
          })
      }).catch(function (e) {
          document.write("loadDetails  catch error\n");

          console.error(e);
      })
  }

  function loadDetails(item) {
      document.write("loadDetails \n");

      var url = item.detailsUrl;
      return fetch(url).then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
          document.write("loadDetails  then\n");

      }).then(function (details) {
          //item.imageUrl = details.sprites.front_default; //do not know sprities ???
          item.height = details.height;
          item.types = details.types;
      }).catch(function (e) {
          console.error(e);
      });
  }

  function showDetails(item) {
      loadDetails(item).then(function () {
      })
  }

  return{
      add: add,
      getAll: getAll,
      loadList: loadList,
      loadDetails: loadDetails,
      showDetails: showDetails
  };
})();

function addListItem(pokemone) {
      var container = document.querySelector('.pokemon-list');
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerText = pokemone.name;
      container.appendChild(listItem); //object breaks
      listItem.appendChild(button);
      button.addEventListener('click', function (event) { //object breaks
          pokemonRepository.showDetails(pokemone);
      });
}
  pokemonRepository.loadList().then(function () {

  pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function (pokemon) {
      addListItem(pokemon);
  })
  })
```

Comment: Couple of issues, if you open your console you'll see that `add is not defined`, once that's changed to `add: addListItem` it complains `getAll` is not defined.

Comment: I got the add and the getAll out from the code to make it shorter, thx.

Comment: Debugging help ... instead of `document.write` you should use `console.log`.  You have a couple of places where you `return response.json();` and _then_ do document.write, which won't be called because you've already `return`ed. Use your browser dev tools debugger… sometimes it's hard to pick where to breakpoint, but you can also add a line in your code that just says `debugger;` and it will stop there if your debugger is open — just "inspect" / "inspect element", or F12 opens the dev tools on most systems.

Comment: Thanks got it finished, that was my document.write...